# Como fazer include de código em arquivos Shell Script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script

Como posso realizar o seguinte processo:

Adicionar o `arquivoa.sh` e `arquivob.sh` no `arquivoc.sh`, e então executar as funções definidas dentro de cada arquivo

arquivoa.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arquivo A"
function funcaoA(){
  echo "Executando a funcao A"
}
```

arquivob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arquivo B"
function funcaoB(){
  echo "Executando a funcao B"
}
```

arquivoc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arquivo C"
funcaoA()
funcaoB()
```

a dúvida é, como realizar o include dos outros arquivos dentro do arquivoc.sh?

estou realizando os testes no Ubuntu 16.

grato

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para adicionar um script dentro de outro e poder realizar o uso das funções é necessário adicionar a seguinte linha no inicio do arquivo

```
source <arquivo_alvo>
```

e para executar a função não é necessário `()`

o código no final ficará como abaixo

arquivoa.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arquivo A"
function funcaoA(){
  echo "Executando a funcao A"
}
```

arquivob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arquivo B"
function funcaoB(){
  echo "Executando a funcao B"
}
```

arquivoc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./arquivoa.sh # ./ para indicar que o arquivo esta na mesma pasta
source ./arquivob.sh

echo "Arquivo C"
funcaoA
funcaoB
```

ao executarmos

```
bash arquivoc.sh
```

teremos a seguinte saída

```
Arquivo A
Arquivo B
Arquivo C
Executando a funcao A
Executando a funcao B
```

perceba que o `echo` de cada arquivo foi executado.
Então tome cuidado para que seu arquivo inserido não atrapalhe o fluxo da aplicação principal.

Answer (score 4):

Olá.
Complementando a excelente resposta dada, vale lembrar que, além de

```
source arquivo.sh
```

você também pode usar

```
. arquivo.sh
```

Caso não haja uma barra no nome do arquivo.sh, o Shell tentará localizar o referido nome de arquivo no PATH do sistema. Ainda, como o arquivo será incluído, arquivo.sh não precisa ser executável.

Segundo a página de manual do Bash, se o mesmo não estiver em modo POSIX, o arquivo será procurado no diretório local, caso não seja encontrado no PATH.